# How to give 4 different colours for each cell in tableview in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, colors, cell

I am using tableview to show data.. i have only one section and rows coming according to JSON response count

here i am using four colours (pink, yellow, green, blue) for cell view background colour

present i am able to show all cells in one colour(yellow).. now i need to show each cell in 4 (pink, yellow, green, blue) colours

i mean if there are two cells then i need to show cell background colour one cell in pink and other in yellow

if there r 4 cells then 4 cells background colour in pink, yellow, green, blue

if there r 8 cells then first 4 cells in pink, yellow, green, blue colour and then next 4 cells in pink, yellow, green, blue colour

like this..

code for tableview cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.homeData?.result?.recents?.count ?? 0
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePostsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomePostsTableViewCell
cell.selectionStyle = .none

cell.catView.backgroundColor = .yellow
cell.categoryLabel.text = category

return cell

}
```

here present all cells showing in yellow colour `cell.catView.backgroundColor = .yellow` but i need to change `cell.catView.backgroundColor` in pink, yellow, green, blue colours..

how? please do guide me

Comment: Add your custom color logic inside `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` - you can read the index path (the cell's index) using `indexPath`.

Comment: if indexPath.row == 0 {

} else if indexPath.row == 1 {

}
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it would be to use to `%` operator. It will get the remainder and correlate that to a color.

It will look something like this

```
switch indexPath.row % 4 {
case 0:
       cell.catView.backgroundColor = .yellow
case 1:
       cell.catView.backgroundColor = .pink
case 2:
       cell.catView.backgroundColor = .green
case 3:
       cell.catView.backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Alternatively, you can store all the colors in an array and use the `%` in that.

```
let colors: [UIColor] = [.yellow, .pink, .green, .blue]
cell.catView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]
```

Comment: Don't forget the `default` in that `switch` statement :D

Answer (score 1):

You can add this logic inside the `cellForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePostsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomePostsTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    switch indexPath.row % 4 {
    case 0:
        cell.catView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    case 1:
        cell.catView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    case 2:
        cell.catView.backgroundColor = .green
    case 3:
        cell.catView.backgroundColor = .blue
    default: break
    }
    
    cell.categoryLabel.text = category
    
    return cell
    
}
```